# Cannot return array and use in another method

Tags: java

I am trying to call my array in my printmessage method. I am getting an error as if I cannot access it outside my method getSum(). Any help? Thanks

```
    public int getSum(int input) {
        int empty[] = new int[input] ;

        for (int i =0;i < input;i++) {
            int num = scan.nextInt();
            empty[i] = num;
            sum = num +sum;
        }
        return sum && empty[];
    }

    public void Printmessage(){
        for(int j = 0; j< empty.length; j++) {
            System.out.print(empty[j]+ " ");
        }
    }  
}
```

Comment: what should be "sum && empty[];"??

Comment: Also, the choice of name 'empty' for an array holding input values is a little unobvious.

Answer (score 1):

You cant return two values from a function ! Change it for this :

```
public int getSum(int input) {
    int empty[] = new int[input] ;

    for (int i =0;i < input;i++) {
        int num = scan.nextInt();
        empty[i] = num;
        sum += num;
    }
    return sum; // ONLY RETURN ONE VALUE !
}


public void Printmessage(){
    for(int j = 0; j< empty.length; j++) {
        System.out.print(empty[j]+ " ");
    }
}
}
```

Comment: int empty[] is define inside of the getSum method so it cannot access from Printmessage()

Answer (score 1):

In your `Printmessage` method, you just reference the array `empty`.  `empty` is a method variable, so it is only accessible within the `getSum` method.  In order to get the return value, you need to actually call the method.

You also return from your `getSum` method with the following line:

```
return sum && empty[];
```

I believe you are trying to return both an `int` and an `int` array here.  You can only return one object from a method.  Since `sum` appears to be an instance variable (you don't declare it in your method), I believe you want to just return the array.

To eliminate both of the above problems, try the following code:

```
public int[] getSum(int input) { //declare the return type as int[] rather than int, since we are now returning an array
    int[] empty = new int[input] ; //move the square brackets over to be after int, not after empty

    for (int i =0;i < input;i++) {
        int num = scan.nextInt();
        empty[i] = num;
        sum = num +sum;


    }
    return empty; //only return one object


}
public void Printmessage(){
    //call the getSum method:
    int[] empty = getSum(5); //here 5 is just an arbitrary value

    for(int j = 0; j< empty.length; j++) {
        System.out.print(empty[j]+ " ");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I'd go further than some answers.

The array `empty` is a local variable of the `getsum` method.  Therefore **it does not exist** except when `getsum` is executing. It is created on entry to `getsum` and destroyed on exit.

You can't use something (in printMessage) that does not exist.

(Secondarily, of course, `sum && empty[]` is not even legal, since firstly `&&` is defined only for boolean operands, and secondly `empty[]` isn't a valid expression)

Answer (score 0):

From the design point of view, you're needlessly making one method do two distinct tasks.  You can usefully split reading the input from calculating the sum.

```
public int[] readInput(int count) {
    int[] data = new int[count];
    for (int i=0; i<count; i++) {
        data[i] = scan.nextInt();
    }
    return data;
}

public int getSum(int[] data) {
    int sum = 0;
    for (int i=0; i<data.length; i++) {
        sum += data[i];
    }
    return sum;
}
```

(I used what I consider to be more appropriate names in some places)

And then...

```
int[] numbers = readInput(5);
int sum = getSum(numbers);
… print from numbers left as exercise for reader …
```